# What is the evidence for the health effects of frying with olive oil

Tags: oil, cooking

There are those who say that consuming food cooked with olive oil (in which olive oil is exposed to high heat) takes away the health benefits or even is detrimental to the health.
What is the evidence for this claim (if any)? Is there evidence of the opposite?

Comment: No health benefits at all https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGGQxJLuVjg    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_o4YBQPKtQ

Comment: I don't know about health benefits, but frying with extra virgin olive oil is a waste of money because heating it causes it to lose its distinctive flavor. After being heated hot enough to cook with, professional chefs were unable to distinguish EVOO from other, much less expensive vegetable oils in a blind taste test.